# Why is there no polynomial time verifier for N Queens

Tags: algorithms, np-hard

The N-Queens in question is referring to the one where it is interested in finding all solutions for some natural number n. I just read about the idea of a verifier being an algorithm that verifies whether it accepts an input and a "certificate".

So say for example that I want to check some configuration of n queens in an n x n chessboard. Can I not loop over each queen and check if every cell that it can reach has another queen in it? And if I finish every queen and find no collision, determine that it is a valid configuration?

What am I missing that makes the verification of this problem non polynomial time?

Comment: $n$-Queens is indeed verifiable in polynomial time. Are you sure you aren't reading about the problem of $n$-Queens *completion*, which is a related but different problem?

Comment: @kviiri I was reading [this paper](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/451b4916-9905-46b0-9906-1cefdfa3b6e1) and I assume that it's the counting version of n-Queens not the completion one and it says that the problem is NP-Hard. Can it still be NP-Hard even if a solution is verifiable in polynomial time.

Comment: The counting version, as in, "return the number of possible arrangements for N"? If that is the problem definition, then your verifier doesn't work – it only checks one configuration, not whether the provided number of configurations is correct. (Sorry, I hesitate to open the pdf provided by a file-sharing site I don't recognize)

Comment: @KennySanders It seems the link to the paper you provided is no longer available. Can you provide a reference to the paper (authors, title, journal. a DOI would also do), so others can find the paper? Thanks!

Comment: Verifying a single configuration is fast. Checking that you found *all* solutions is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything.  Verifying that a candidate solution is valid (i.e., that no queen attacks any other) can be done in polynomial time.

Finding a solution might take more than polynomial time (I don't know).  Also, checking whether $n$ is the smallest possible value such that you can place $n$ queens in a valid way also might take more than polynomial time (I don't know).

Comment: Well, the input is just $n$, right?  So the input size is $\log n$.  Even encoding an arbitrary candidate solution takes $\Omega(n \log n)$ bits, which is not polynomial in the input size.  Right?

Comment: @NealYoung, For which problem?  For verifying a candidate solution, the input is the set of positions of the $n$ queens.  It takes at least $\Theta(n \log n)$ bits to represent such an input.  Therefore, the input size is $\Theta(n \log n)$.  Which statement in the answer are you disagreeing with?

Comment: Good point.  I guess I assumed "polynomial time" meant polynomial in the size of the input to the N-queens problem (which is just the integer N).  For the interpretation where the poster means polynomial in the size of a *configuration*, I agree with your answer.

Comment: @D.W. I was reading [this paper](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/451b4916-9905-46b0-9906-1cefdfa3b6e1) and I assume that it's the counting version of n-Queens not the completion one and it says that the problem is NP-Hard. Can it still be NP-Hard even if a solution is verifiable in polynomial time.

Furthermore, Can you explain a bit how you guys came up with the input size being **log n**, and how it takes **n log n** to represent

Comment: @KennySanders, the input size is the number of bits to represent the input.  It takes $\log n$ bits to represent the integer $n$, $\log (n^2) = 2 \log n$ bits to represent the location of a single queen on a $n\times n$ board, and $2n \log n$ bits to represent the location of $n$ queens on a $n \times board$.  For your other questions, you might find it helpful to learn about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP and about counting problems: counting problems can be significantly harder.

Comment: @NealYoung If I may just clarify, I just now understood where the **n log n** part comes from. Does this mean that the verification is not polynomial in the input size? Thank you

Comment: What are you considering the input to be?  If it's just $n$, then the input size is $\Theta(\log n)$.  If it's a configuration, then the input size is $\Theta(n\log n)$ (or $\Theta(n)$, depending on your model).   Note that $n\log n$ is exponentially bigger than $\log n$, and the time to verify a configuration is exponential in $\log n$ but polynomial in $n\log n$.

Answer (score -1):

Problem: Given an integer n >= 1, is there a way to put n queens on an n by n chessboard so that none attacks another one?

The algorithm “return “yes” if and only if n != 2 and n != 3” may be correct and runs in O(1). Assume this is not true or not provable.

I’m unsure if an actual solution can be found in polynomial time in n or not, but that is just my opinion. If you put queens on the first rows, it’s quite possible easy to put queens on the first 950 of 1000 rows, and not very hard to fill the remaining rows.

It can’t be done in polynomial time in the size of n. That would be a polynomial in log(n) and you can’t even copy a solution in that time.